# MapView partially greying out my map

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am developing an android app so I am still in "debug mode" in terms of signing my app. The MapView that I am using used to work so far but since today (maybe yesterday) the map shows greyed out areas. (Compare the following image.)
[image: MapView with greyed out areas]

Does anybody know the reason for this?

**[EDIT]**

I have installed my app on two other devices (Samsung Galaxy Ace and Galaxy S2). On the Ace it shows the exact same behavior with the greyed out "chessboard" tiles. On the Galaxy S2 however it does not.

I have also thrown away the debug certificate and generated a new fingerprint and API key. But that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to narrow down the problem I found that it seems to be related to the streetview feature. When I started to code the mapview into my app I set the streetview feature to true:

```
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

When I turn it off (set to false) the greyed out areas disappear. 
I have not further investigated this but for now my problem is solved (so I wrote this as an answer).